# What is the purpose of the super() call in TS subclasses?

Tags: typescript

Besides being annoying and making it so that every single subclass needs to be touched when a parent class is updated...

Answer (score 13):

Consider the following code:

```
class A {
    protected sum: number;

    constructor(protected x: number, protected y: number) {
        this.sum = this.x + this.y;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        super(x, y);
    }
}
```

The call to `super` in the ctor of class `B` calls the ctor of class `A`, and if we look at the compiled javascript code:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
var A = (function () {
    function A(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.sum = this.x + this.y;
    }
    return A;
}());
var B = (function (_super) {
    __extends(B, _super);
    function B(x, y) {
        _super.call(this, x, y);
    }
    return B;
}(A));
```

It should be clear why we do that, because otherwise everything that happens in the ctor of `A` wouldn't happen, that is members `x`, `y` and `sum` wouldn't be assigned in the instances of class `B`.

You might then ask "well, fine, but why doesn't that happen automatically? why can't the compiler just call `super` for me?"
That's a fair question, and I can think of 2 main reasons:

(1) Because sometimes you want to want to do something before calling `super`, for example:

```
class A {
    protected sum: number;

    constructor(protected x: number, protected y: number) {
        this.sum = this.x + this.y;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        if (x % 2 === 0) {
            super(x, y);
        } else {
            super(x + 1, y);
        }
    }
}
```

You must call `super` before you access `this` in the ctor of `B`.

(2) It makes it explicit that this is what's happening, otherwise you might not expect it to happen because you don't see it.

This requirement is only valid for constructors, class methods are not required to call their super, but you are free to do so if you want to execute the parent method functionality.

Comment: That makes sense. But couldn't a method like _preconstruct() exist where those subclass's pre-super functions are executed? Seems like a better way to go than forcing each subclass to replicate the conditions of its parent.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference between what you're suggesting and the current `super` way of doing things.

Comment: I think @user3583223 might be suggesting a `_preconstruct()` function could be available ONLY for child classes that need some logic in the call to `super()`. All child classes that do not need any special logic could just have an implicit call to `super()`. In other words, `_preconstruct()` would be completely optional, whereas calls to `super()` are not optional.

Comment: @MadScone I think that that will be more confusing, when will this `_preconstruct()` be called? before the parent ctor? after the extending ctor? in between? This `super()` might be too explicit but it's very clear what's going on

Comment: Yes I don't agree with it, just clarifying with what I thought @user3583223 meant.

Comment: If you need `_preconstruct()`, it suggests your constructor is doing too much work. Such logic would be better moved into an `initialise()` method. Within `Derived#initialise` you can call `super.initialise()` at any time.